# How to pass column names into subquery from an outer query in teradata

Tags: t-sql, teradata

So in TSQL, I can do something like

```
select * from tbl1 a 
where a.key1 = (select b.key1 from tbl2 b where a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2)
```

I tried to implement the same concept in teradata, but no luck. How can I do this in teradata?

Comment: Can you show the actual SQL? Of course a Correlated Subquery is valid syntax in Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.key1 FROM tbl2b WHERE a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2 = b.key2)
```

You might also get the result you want using a join:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl2 b
    ON a.key1 = b.key1
WHERE a.key2 = b.key2
```

Comment: In the second query,  to be equivalent to OP initial query,,  you should use "a.*" instead of only "*"